# Smallest witness for checking the primality of a number

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

In this link

https://primes.utm.edu/prove/prove2_3.html

it is stated that the smallest witness for a composite number is always 
less than $2ln(n)^2$ , assuming the extended Riemann-hypothesis.

> Is there a known bound for a witness without making unproven asumptions ?

Comment: $n/4$ is a bound, as there seem to be infinitely many numbers which have almost that many false witnesses.  This may be much higher than necessary, as that assumes all $n/4$ false witnesses could cluster at the beginning, but you'd need something that showed that wasn't possible.  Google Books shows Bach/Shalit 1996, page 315 has some discussion and references.

Comment: Re "seem to be" in my last comment: there are not more than n/4, and from what I can tell it is believed there are infinitely many values that come arbitrarily close to that limit.  But we haven't proven there are infinitely many.  It doesn't have a large bearing on either the bound (n/4) or what Jack's answer was about -- can we reduce the n/4 bound at all.  His answer seems to say, yes we can reduce that a *lot*, but also that it is still much higher than the 2ln^2(n) bound.  In practice even the latter makes a slow test at reasonable sizes.

Comment: What is known about the smallest witness of Carmichael-numbers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For short, the answer is *yes, but it is unbelievably weaker*.

In particular, it changes the expected complexity from "polynomial" to "exponential".

---

Now, the long answer: by combining the Burgess' inequality with the Vinogradov's amplification trick (based on the [Dickman function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function)) it is possible to prove that $\eta_p$, the least quadratic non-residue $\!\!\pmod{p}$, is:

$$ \ll p^{\frac{1}{4\sqrt{e}}} $$
that is roughly $p^{\frac{1}{7}}$. Similar unconditional bounds are known for the least generator $\!\!\pmod{p}$.

On the other hand, an unconditional result of Montgomery (that is an elegant improvement of a previous result of Chowla) shows that for an infinite number of primes, $$\eta_p \gg \log(p)\log\log\log(p)$$
holds.

Comment: Link to recent arxiv paper with this bound described:  http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.7556